# Javascript Flood fill algorithm using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, flood-fill

I have 5 X 5 matrix in which 1 represents land and 0 represent water. Need to create a function which will iterate through the matrix and returns the number of land it finds. Diagonal 1's needs to be ignored.

I am stuck with my program. Help much appreciated.

```
var arr = [
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
];
```

I have a written a function which uses the above matrix to find the number of land.

```
function findLand(arr) {

var check = [],
    cntr = 0;

for(let i=0 ;i<arr.length; i++) {
    check = [];
    traverse(i, 0);
}
function traverse(x, y) {
    if(x<0 || y<0 || x > arr.length-1 || y > arr[0].length-1) {
        return;
    }

    if(arr[x][y]!=1 || check.indexOf(x+'_'+y)!=-1) {
        return;
    }
    check.push(x+'_'+y);

    traverse(x, y+1);
    traverse(x, y-1);
    traverse(x-1, y);
    traverse(x+1, y);
}
```

}

```
findLand(matrix)
```

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of groups or just the total land (number of ones)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. what the function should return is the number of 1's together, in the above matrix we have **3 lands**.

Comment: `return check.length;` maybe?

Comment: Yes number of 1's together which is 3

Comment: I tried that `check.length` but since i have given the condition `if(arr[x][y]!=1` it ignores the 1's after zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get both the count and the coordinates of the land masses. You need to iterate though the whole array — right now you are only iterating through the first column so you'll miss land masses that don't began on that edge. With each iteration you can make a new empty `current` array. At the end you'll push that array into the array 'lands' which will have your final result. We'll also keep a `visited` array so you don't have to loop through the lands matrix:

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
];

function findLand(arr) {
    var lands = [],        // the current group
        visited = new Set  // coords we've seen (set is quicker to lookup)
 
    // iterate the rows AND columns
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            if (visited.has(i+'_'+j)) continue // don't call function on visited coords
            let land = traverse(i,j)
            if(land) {                // land will be undefined if traverse returns undefined
                lands.push(land);
            }
        } 
    }
    function traverse(x, y, current = []) { // keep current local
        if(x<0 || y<0 || x > arr.length-1 || y > arr[0].length-1) {
            return;
        }
        if(arr[x][y]!=1 || visited.has(x+'_'+y)) {
            return;
        }
        current.push(x+'_'+y);
        visited.add(x+'_'+y)
        traverse(x, y+1, current);
        traverse(x, y-1, current);
        traverse(x-1, y, current);
        traverse(x+1, y, current);
        return current   // should hold one complete land mass
    }
    return lands
}

let lands = findLand(arr)
console.log("lands found: ", lands.length )
console.log("lands: ", lands)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark Meyer, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks once again for correcting me.